# nginx + fastCGI for PHP error_page

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, custom-error-pages

I set up custom error pages in nginx with fastCGI for PHP like this way and it works:

```
root <FOLDER>;
error_page 404 /error.php?404;
location = /error.php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:1234;
    root  <FOLDER>;
}
```

But since I have one error.php for every HTTP error codes, I wanted to set up in a general form. The problem is that I don't know if nginx provide the error code to be passed by GET to error.php

I am looking for something like:

```
root <FOLDER>;
error_page 500 501 502 401 402 403 404 /error.php?NGINX_ERROR_CODE;
location = /error.php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:1234;
    root  <FOLDER>;
}
```

The problem is `NGINX_ERROR_CODE` which I don't know if it provides such a thing to set up general error_page handler.

Is it any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around, it doesn't initially appear that there's a var for it.

You can, however, set multiple error page directives.

```
error_page 401 /error.php?e=401;
error_page 402 /error.php?e=402;
error_page 403 /error.php?e=403;
error_page 404 /error.php?e=404;
error_page 500 501 502 /error.php?e=50x;
```

and so on.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am currently doing. Just wanted to know if it could be simplified :( Because with that, a simple change will require lots of config changes, which I want to avoid :(

Comment: Looks unavoidable to me, alas. If you're looking at changing the name of the file readily though, you *could* try setting it as a variable with `set $foo bar` -- maybe something like `set $errorpage error.php?e=` would work best.