# Nginx custom error_page with php

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-server

I'm new into nginx and in order to test it I'm migrating from Apache and all I got left is setting up the custom error pages.

These pages are php files (for multi language purposes), I have tried many of the methods from StackOverflow but I cannot figure out how to make it.

Some of them are:

- [nginx-php-fpm-custom-error-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486868/nginx-php-fpm-custom-error-pages)
- [nginx-fastcgi-for-php-error-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739436/nginx-fastcgi-for-php-error-page)
- [nginx-error-pages-one-location-rule-to-fit-them-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621915/nginx-error-pages-one-location-rule-to-fit-them-all)

So far I've created a file `/etc/nginx/common/default-error-pages.conf` to include it on the vhosts. This file contains:

```
error_page 400 /error/400.php;
error_page 401 /error/401.php;
error_page 403 /error/403.php;
error_page 404 /error/404.php;

error_page 500 /error/500.php;
error_page 503 /error/503.php;

location /error/ {
    alias /var/www/error/;
    autoindex on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/error/;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

    # fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

The php files are located in `/var/www/error` if I enable the autoindex I'm able to view them from the browser all the files but if I click in any of them the default 404 page is shown.

I have created a symlink of one of those files to a testing site and it gets executed correcly even the css loads as expected.

I've tried nesting the locations and including this config file at the top of the site `server` block.

If I change the extension of the php error files to html they are correctly served.

The nginx site is similar to this (file simplified):

```
server {
        listen 4430 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:4430 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name test.local;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;
        # execute php files "helper"
        include common/php-files.conf;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        include common/default-error-pages.conf;

        location / {
                # autoindex on;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

How is supposed to be configured? I've changed it so many times that I don't know what else to try.

Nginx logs files don't reveal any unexpected error/configuration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To access `/var/www/error/400.php` using the URI `/error/400.php` requires a `root /var/www;` statement, **not** `root /var/www/error/;`

Comment: Changed and it worked, thank you a lot, I also nested the `location` blocks to catch the configuration of the php files and do not mess up with the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got wrong the `root` as [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) told in the comment below the post.

After changing it to the suggested one all worked perflectly.

I also nested the `location` blocks so the php files are correctly handled, as others are being processed with `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` to catch the http errors.

So the config stays as:

```
error_page 403 /error/403.php;
error_page 404 /error/404.php;

error_page 500 /error/500.php;
error_page 503 /error/503.php;

location /error/ {
    root /var/www/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }
}
```